# Alternatives to fmincon in python for constrained non-linear optimisation problems

Tags: python, matlab, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize

I am having trouble solving an optimisation problem in python, involving ~20,000 decision variables. The problem is non-linear and I wish to apply both bounds and constraints to the problem. In addition to this, the gradient with respect to each of the decision variables may be calculated.

The bounds are simply that each decision variable must lie in the interval [0, 1] and there is a monotonic constraint placed upon the variables, i.e each decision variable must be greater than the previous one.

I initially intended to use the L-BFGS-B method provided by the `scipy.optimize` package however I found out that, while it supports bounds, it does not support constraints.

I then tried using the SQLSP method which does support both constraints and bounds. However, because it requires more memory than L-BFGS-B and I have a large number of decision variables, I ran into memory errors fairly quickly.

The paper which this problem comes from used the `fmincon` solver in Matlab to optimise the function, which, to my knowledge, supports the application of both bounds and constraints in addition to being more memory efficient than the SQLSP method provided by scipy.  I do not have access to Matlab however.

Does anyone know of an alternative I could use to solve this problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `SciPy` solvers you mentioned are for small, dense problems, while your problem is large and sparse. Large, sparse NLP solvers are readily available although not all of them are free. Some good solvers are available through [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/) for testing.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. I don't have much experience with optimization and am still learning so - just out of interest - how were you able to tell that my problem was sparse? Is it just because the problem contains many decision variables? Thanks again for the help provided.

Comment: Educated guess. Most large models are sparse. Large scale solvers try to exploit this.

Comment: @M.Jagger Have you found any alternative to fmincon in python? I am facing the same issue...